# Drools actions with conditional logic, how to express

Tags: drools

I have a rule like this from a Decision Table

```
rule "Tips 2_525"
    salience 65011
    when
        ub:User(ub.getDrinksCount() > 0, ub.getMissedDrink() >= 2)
    then
        ub.getTip("Attract waiter in "+ub.getAvgTime()+ " minutes")==null?ub.putTip("Attract waiter in "+ub.getAvgTime()+ " minutes",20):ub.putTip("Attract waiter in "+ub.getAvgTime()+ " minutes",(ub.getTip("Attract waiter in "+ub.getAvgTime()+ " minutes").getValue()+2));
end
```

The "==" causes a problem here with "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable" and "Syntax error on token "==", invalid AssignmentOperator"

What I am trying to do is check that this particular tip has an entry in the Map before I increment the minute count, if it does not then I put the initial value in the Map. Is there a way of doing this that satisfies the syntactic constraints of drools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conditional expression (!) is not a statement in Java and therefore not valid on a Drools RHS. Rewrite:

```
ub.putTip("Attract waiter in "+ub.getAvgTime()+ " minutes",
          ub.getTip("Attract waiter in "+ub.getAvgTime()+ " minutes")==null
          ? 20
          : ub.getTip("Attract waiter in "+ub.getAvgTime()+ " minutes").getValue()+2));
```

Comment: Thx, a Dooh! moment for me.